# How to Extract Data from a Nested Array in MongoDB Using Aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
`[
      { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      { $lookup: { from: "cat", localField: "cat", foreignField: "_id", as: "childs" ,pipeline:[{$project:{_id:1,catName:1,patName:1}}] }},
      { $lookup: { from: "patName", localField: "pat", foreignField: "_id", as: "parents",pipeline:[{$project:{_id:1,patName:1,status:1,thumbnail:1,desc:1}}] }},
      { $lookup: 
        { from: "contentsources", localField: "contentSource.contentId", foreignField: "_id", as: "contentsources",
         pipeline:[{$project:{_id:1,businessName:1,thumbnail:1,type:1,status:1,createdDate:1}}]

      }},

      { $lookup: { from: "cha", localField: "cha", foreignField: "_id", as: "cha",pipeline:[{$project:{_id:1,chan:1,cha:1,status:1,status:1}}] }},
      { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField: "_id", as: "users",
      pipeline:[
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "roles", 
            localField: "role", 
            foreignField: "_id", 
            as: "userroles"
          }
        },
        {$project:{_id:1,fullName:1,profileName:1,email:1,icon:1,status:1,urerRole:{'$first':'$userroles.name'},position:1}}]
      } },
      {
        $project:{
          tribeLogo:1,
          name:1,
          type:1,
          desc:1,
          createdDate:1,
          parents:1,
          childs:1,
          contentsources:1,
          rsschannels:1,
          users:1,
          status:1,
          contentSource:1
        }
      }
    ]`
```

This is the query I am using
my contnet source look like this

```
        "contentSource": [
            {
                "contentId": "64c252e2c2c4aaabd4d729ab",
                "upVote": 1,
                "downVote": 0,
                "totalVote": 1,
                "syndicateScore": 100
            },
            {
                "contentId": "64c258d0c2c4aaabd4d72ac5",
                "upVote": 0,
                "downVote": 0,
                "totalVote": 0,
                "syndicateScore": 0
            }
        ],
```

I want data in this format I want to do lookup into contentId which extract businessName,thumbnail,status

which look like this

```
"contentSource": [
            {
                "contentId": {businessName:"xyz",thumbnail:"image",status:"active"},
                "upVote": 1,
                "downVote": 0,
                "totalVote": 1,
                "syndicateScore": 100
            },
            {
                "contentId": {businessName:"xyz",thumbnail:"image",status:"active"},
                "upVote": 0,
                "downVote": 0,
                "totalVote": 0,
                "syndicateScore": 0
            }
        ],
```

Note: Ignore rest of the fields

I have tried doing unwind but I am unable to do group here I am getting two document in a result for for content sources

Comment: you can use below tool for the parsing data from JSON 
https://www.jstoolset.com/json-query

Comment: Why do you `"$lookup"` from `"cha"` and then never use, nor `"$project"` those results?  I'm not a _mongooser_, but couldn't much of what you do here be done with `populate`?